# Windows won't boot after booting once to Linux Mint from grub

Tags: linux-mint, boot, windows, dual-boot, boot-loader

[image]I have a Windows 10 system. I booted to Linux Mint from USB once. While shutting down, it asked me to remove the installation device and then press Enter. I simply pressed Enter without removing the USB. Now, windows won't load and gets stuck with a black screen and a blinking cursor.

I can boot into Linux Mint from the USB and the main HDD shows up but I can't open it. The error that shows up is: "Unable to mount location" - Can't mount file.

The `sudo fdsik -l` log is:

```
dev/sda1          2048    999423    997376   487M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       1001470 976771071 975769602 465.3G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1001472 976771071 975769600 465.3G 8e Linux LVM
```

sda1 should be ntfs and sda5 should also be ntfs if I am correct?

EDIT: from gparted it appears as if sda1 is ntfs file format.

Any ideas or help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you use live boot, or install the O/S?

Comment: I did a live boot from a usb stick.

Answer (score 0):

Try booting from a [gParted live CD](http://gparted.org/download.php) (using a CD disk) if possible and check with the gParted application all disks partitions and file systems.

If it shows that `/dev/sda1` and/or `/dev/sda5` is a Linux file system (`extX`) the partitions or the partition table are somehow corrupted.

I would [check if the disk is corrupt](https://www.tecmint.com/check-linux-hard-disk-bad-sectors-bad-blocks/) with `badblocks` in Linux.

You can try pressing F8 while booting from Windows and enter in safe mode or try to repair the system.

Another thing: Try with the HDD Regenerator tool, it will try to repair demagnetized blocks on your hard drive(s), it will take a few hours.

If none of these works, I'm afraid you'll have to reformat and reinstall the system.

Good luck.